# Is it possible to filter out log items based on strings or regex for instance from the live tail?

Tags: logentries

I have a test app with heroku with the logentries add on.

I was wondering if it was possible to filter out some types of logs from the live tail, in my case all logs with the terms "heroku router"

Comment: found an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply negate your search terms. For the case you've specified, the following works:

`-"heroku router"`